# Unable to Install Packages in VIrtual Environment Python 2.7 Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu

In My Environment i have Python 3.6.3 Installed Via Anaconda and i also have Python 2.7(Came With Distro).So i am trying to create a virtual environment for this course [Course Link](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/)  as the code is in Python 2.7.

So i create a virtualenv with virtualenv --python= "python2.7 path" "path to project directory"

Then i activate the given virtual environment but while installing,i get a error like this [image: Error Image]

Any idea how i can rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to create your virtual environment with spaces in the path name. You should set up your virtual environment at a path without any spaces.

When you set up an environment, all of the scripts and executables relating to that environment are placed in the bin directory.  Some of the scripts reference interpreters such as bash. In the case of a bash script, the `#!` first line of the script will evaluate incorrectly as it comes across a space. In your case, these scripts are starting with the following first line:

```
 #!/home/dhruv/Python 2.7 venv/bin/python
```

Note that this will cause errors because the script will be intepreted as the command `/home/dhruv/Python` with the arguments `2.7` and `venv/bin/python`. i.e. it is looking for an interpreter `/home/dhruv/Python` (which does not exist) and it is trying to give it two arguments.

Comment: You are absolutely right!! How did you exactly figure out this issue?

Comment: I had similar issues with spaces in path names many times before when I work on any unix system or unix terminal emulator. Always try replace space with underscore or use camel case when dealing with paths. Glad to help

Comment: One last thing,have you tried to install a package called matplotlib in a virtual environment?

Comment: You should be able to install via `pip install matplotlib`. Before you execute this, you must  first  activate the virtual environment.  If you still have issues please raise a new question and you should get an answer. Good luck

Comment: Thank You for all your help.Was able to get everything working Properly as needed.